# Run appplication configuration async during startup

Tags: c#, async-await, initialization

I have a piece of code that configures a part of the application that must be executed during application startup. Unfortunately, that takes some time so I would like to run it as a background operation to speed up the application start. Fortunately, the configuration itself it can be run separately and does not require UI thread. At some later point, there are components that rely on the configuration being finished, so they are supposed to wait for the configuration to be finished.

Code before

```
public class App
{
    public static Configuration Config { get; set; } = new Configuration();

    public static void Main()
    {
        Configure();
        // .... run other stuff
        var service = new Service();
    }

    private void Configure()
    {
        try
        {
            Config.Add(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.Property1), 4);
            Config.Add(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.Property2), 2);
            Config.Add(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.Property3), 42);
            // there are tons of these configurations which takes a few seconds to run
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // show message to the user and shut down application
        }
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
        var config = App.Config; // use config
    }
}
```

Now I wondered what is the best approach to do this. My first draft was this:

```
public class App
{
    public static Task ConfigurationTask { get; set; }
    public static Configuration Config { get; set; } = new Configuration();

    public static void Main()
    {
        ConfigurationTask = ConfigureAsync();
        // .... run other stuff
        var service = new Service();
    }

    private static async Task ConfigureAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Config.Add(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.Property1), 4);
                Config.Add(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.Property2), 2);
                Config.Add(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.Property3), 42);
                // there are tons of these configurations which takes a few seconds to run
            });
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // show message to the user and shut down application
        }
    }
}

public class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
        App.ConfigurationTask.Wait();
        var config = App.Config; // use config
    }
}
```

But I am sure that blocking the task in the service is not a good idea. What would be the best practice to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the difference between these 2 codes? Whatever you will initialize the service after the configuration finishes loading.

Comment: In the second one, the "other stuff" which is executed after `ConfigureAsync` can run in parallel

Comment: Can the other stuff run in parallel?

Comment: Unfortunately it can't

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the application fast enough for the end users, skipping the configuration part, then `Lazy<T>` is probably what you're looking for.

```
private static Lazy<Configuration> _config = new Lazy<Configuration>(Configure);

private static Configuration Configure()
{
    var config = new Configuration();
    try
    {
        config.Add(typeof(Configuration), nameof(Configuration.Property1), 4);
        config.Add(typeof(Configuration), nameof(Configuration.Property2), 2);
        config.Add(typeof(Configuration), nameof(Configuration.Property3), 42);
        // there are tons of these configurations which takes a few seconds to run
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // show message to the user and shut down application
    }
    return config;
}

public static Configuration Config => _config.Value;

public static void Main()
{
    var service = new Service();
}
public class Service
{
    public Service()
    {
        // the Configure() will run at this moment.                
        var config = Config;
    }
}
```

Via `Lazy<T>` above, the tons of `Add(agr1, agr2, agr3)` jobs will be executed only when the `Service` class is instantiated and tries to reference `Config` member.

This is what [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-8.0#remarks) says.

> Use lazy initialization to defer the creation of a large or resource-intensive object, or the execution of a resource-intensive task, particularly when such creation or execution might not occur during the lifetime of the program.

If you need to initialize the `Configuration` object as fast as you possibly can, then the second example may be fine too. Changing the constructor would be more likely to have because, like you mentioned, blocking a thread is not a good idea.

```
public class Service
{
    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        await App.ConfigurationTask;
        var config = App.Config; // use config
        // do other stuff
    }
}
.
.
.
public static void Main()
{
    ConfigurationTask = ConfigureAsync();
    // .... run other stuff
    var service = new Service();
    await service.RunAync();
}
```